# Round negative result from CASE WHEN statement to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have this query

```
SELECT [A], [B], [C], [D], [E] CASE  WHEN [A] <> '' THEN [B] + [C]  WHEN [A] = '' THEN [B] - [C]  ELSE ''  END AS [Result]  FROM [TableA]
```

But, [B] - [C] resulting a negative value and I wanted to round it to zero, any idea how?

Comment: Also this meta question, why can't I go to new line with double space

Comment: ?I have no idea what your last comment means?

Comment: I can't insert new line, I searched Google and it says use double space, but when I did, it just literally double space and not going to a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use another nested `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT [A], [B], [C], [D], [E],
       CASE WHEN [A] <> '' THEN [B] + [C]
            WHEN [A] = '' THEN
                CASE WHEN [B] - [C] < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [B] - [C] END
            END AS [Result]
FROM [TableA];
```

I removed the `ELSE` condition in the outer `CASE` expression, because it appears that this `CASE` expression is generating numeric values.  Therefore, it doesn't make sense to have empty string as one possible value.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the case expression by using a *values* contructor to first evaluate `B - C` and then use this in the case expression; there are only two possibilities when comparing `A` being equal or not-equal (not considering nullability).

```
select A, B, C, D, E,
  case when A = '' then BminusC else B + C end as Result  
from TableA
cross apply(values(Iif(B - C < 0, 0, B - C)))v(BminusC);
```